# How can renormalised constants and perturbation expansions both be valid?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams

When we compute expectation values in QFT we use feynman diagrams/perturbation expansion.  However, this requires the coupling constant to be small, however, when we renormalize we end up with coupling constants etc being infinite and yet we still use a perturbation expansion.

I guess a similar question is, in the path integral approach, we integrate the field over all values, but surely we will then get a situation where, for example $\lambda\phi^4$, will be too big to expand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does a perturbation theory make sense in quantum field theory?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336383/how-does-a-perturbation-theory-make-sense-in-quantum-field-theory)